# SQLite Insert Problem Only with Bash Script

Tags: bash, sqlite

it's produce this insert for sqlite INSERT INTO HistoryTrade (Symbol,ValMedPerc,HowZero,ValRepeat,HowTrade,OpenPriceTrade,OkorNot,GainPercent,DataOpen,DataClose) VALUES ('LUNAUSDT','13.89','1.0','2.00','20','1.4299','0','1','0','0');
if  i copy  this  and use un db browser and execute it , it work but  if run the script return this  error

```
zione Row riuscito.
de made INSERT INTO HistoryTrade (Symbol,ValMedPerc,HowZero,ValRepeat,HowTrade,OpenPriceTrade,OkorNot,GainPercent,DataOpen,DataClose) VALUES ('LUNAUSDT','13.89','1.0','2.00','20','1.4299','0','1','0','0');
Error: in prepare, no such table: HistoryTrade (1)
Errore durante l'inserimento nel database.
```

```
_Sqlite_Insert_Row(){
    
    local database_name="$1"
    local NameTable="$2"
    local NameColumn="$3"
    local NameValue="$4"

    # Verifica se la stringa di input contiene il carattere "|"
    if echo "${NameColumn}" | grep -q "|"; then

    # Sostituisci il carattere "|" con la virgola ","
    NameColumnOK="${NameColumn//|/,}"
    NameValueOK="${NameValue//|/','}"
    # Sostituisci le virgole vuote tra virgole con uno zero
    NameValueOK="${NameValueOK//,,/,0,}"
    if [[ "${NameValueOK}" == *, ]]; then
            NameValueOK="${NameValueOK}0"
    fi
        
    # Aggiungi virgolette singole attorno a ciascun valore di stringa
    NameValueOK="'$(echo "${NameValueOK}" | sed "s/,/','/g")'"

    # Creo la query SQL con i valori dell'array
      
      sql="INSERT INTO ${NameTable} (${NameColumnOK}) VALUES (${NameValueOK});"
           echo "de made ${sql}"
           
        if sqlite3 "${database_name}" "${sql}"; then
            echo "Inserimento riuscito."
            return 0
        else
            echo "Errore durante l'inserimento nel database."
            return 1
        fi
      
    else
      echo "La stringa di input non contiene il carattere '|'."
      output_string="${input_string}"
    fi
}


# Creazione della stringa con parole senza virgolette e spazi
my_string="Symbol|ValMedPerc|HowZero|ValRepeat|HowTrade|OpenPriceTrade|OkorNot|GainPercent|DataOpen|DataClose"
my_array_val="LUNAUSDT|13.89|1.0|2.00|20|1.4299|0|1||"
_Sqlite_Insert_Row "BinCexExchangeInfo" "HistoryTrade" "$my_string" "$my_array_val"
```

i try also to change ${NameTable} to $NameTable  or '${NameTable}' or "${NameTable}"  but nothing  anyone have ideda??  at this link  my db https://mega.nz/file/r9Mj2RqK#9oZ8kY0NIjVcxfn2-d5vZey-oLdLYtkJU2TUR8PwEi4

Comment: I don't see in your code, where you would create the table `HistoryTrade`....

Comment: you can download  directly my database  , the table exist and i created with db browser day ago

Comment: Maybe, but as you can see from the error message, a database of **this** name does not exist at the time where the script has been run. Therefore your problem is not the insertion in a table, but the fact that the table can't be found.  As a first step, I would [print a list of tables](https://www.sqlitetutorial.net/sqlite-show-tables/).

Comment: but  exist this table  and  i  am sure exist i run this script now  and  return me  the same error, i add the database  you can look it

Answer (score 0):

Just add the file (database) extension on your function invocation

```
_Sqlite_Insert_Row "BinCexExchangeInfo.db" "HistoryTrade" "$my_string" "$my_array_val"
```

Comment: many many  many thanks  a look  3 milion time  and  i neve saw  ooooooo  thanks